# hot to install pgsql php on mac

Tags: php, postgresql

i look the bocument at http://blog.visionsource.org/2010/05/31/installing-php-extensions-on-mac-os-x-under-xampp/
try install the pgsql extend, success build the extend, and copy the pgsql.so to /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626

but i get a warning when i tap 'php' conmment in the terminal:
PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'pgsql.so' in Unknown on line 0

please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

phpize seems to want to set things up to compile in 32 bit mode(i386) instead of 64 bit mode(x86_64). If you tell the compiler and linker to use both 32 and 64 bit modes, it should work. These commands fixed it for me:

```
$ phpize
$ export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
$ export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp"
$ export CCFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
$ export CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
$ export LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load"
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```